# How to create mobile apps that can recognize location/orientation of 2D imges from the CAM

Tags: mobile, opencv, 3d, augmented-reality

I am interested in finding out how mobile applications can recognize the location and orientation of a pre-determined 2D image/logo/glyph via live video from the camera.

For iPhone or Android, what libraries are used, and more importantly, are there any examples out there that demonstrate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and face detection and Haar classifiers